# PHP 4.4.9 - domxml_open_mem() function problem

Tags: php, xml

I am getting this error in PHP 4.4.9

Fatal error: Call to undefined function domxml_open_mem()
while executing the following line
$dom = domxml_open_mem($xmlData);

How can i know domxml is enabled or not by using phpinfo() ?

How to fix this error? Please anyone help me!!!!

Comment: Just so it's said : you really should migrate your application to PHP 5.3 : PHP 4 is not maintained anymore, at all *(and it's already been so for a few years)*

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!function_exists('domxml_open_mem')) {
    die('Required function does not exist');
}
```

http://php.net/function_exists

As for how to fix it: Upgrade your PHP installation to a version that hasn't been dead for years and that includes the extensions you need.